# new mac user, need help taking ownership of a mac airbook

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, apple-id

I am totally new to Mac environment, trying to develop an ionic/cordova hybrid app. I have just inherited a Macbook Air from a former teammate who left us in a hurry. Yeah. I have a login acct and root access to this machine.

There is a whole bunch of libraries and other code on this machine incl Xcode. But when I try to update it, it asks for the password of the former teammate's appleid. I have my own appleid, but how to change this ownership? Or, would it make better sense, delete the old Xcode and other libraries and install all anew? The OS also needs update but stuck the same way.

Running OS X Yosemite.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: From security point of view, former employees manager should take the ownership of all the data in Macintosh & your IT department should take the ownership of Macintosh. Once data is dealt with, IT should either find a way to give you the access of data & Macintosh or just wipe out the OS and give you a fresh OS to start with.

Comment: Try this thread or site or whatever: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hehe, @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like, *IT department*? It's been long since I worked in a place with such thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you buy an App in AppStore, they are connected to the appleid of the buyer. This holds true for free apps, since in Apple's system, you also bought them for 0 currency. If you delete this app (just drop xcode into the trash bin and empty it), you can buy it again from your appleID. this will delete the App, but not its meta files. You will find the App in /Application. Furthermore, please also buy your current operation system in the AppStore. Current OS is Yosemite. It's for free, too, but if you start downloading it and then immediately stop it again, your AppleID can now use the recovery. this is vital when you run into any bugs and have to reinstall the system. There is always a work around, but preventive action makes it so much easier. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Wipe it & start over.

Everything on the machine currently belongs to its last owner's AppleID, including the OS itself.
This cannot be changed, other than by totally wiping it & starting afresh with your ID.

Apple's paradigm is opposite to that of MS. Apps, OS & data belong to a person, not a machine. This makes migrating machines easy, but transferring ownership to another person difficult.

It goes without saying to copy off any important data first...

The OS itself is free, & can become yours by the simple expedient of holding down Cmd/R at the chimes, then going to Disk Utility & erasing the existing main OS partition [you can do this because it will be booted from a small emergency partition]. You can then download & install an OS [it will be the one that originally came with the machine, update later] You sign into this with your ID & follow the setup.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be doing this, it's your IT department's job. But.

1. Your version of XCode might have a preference for this. Take a look in Preferences > Accounts.
2. Nuke the stored auth in Keychain, named something like "daw2.apple.com NOT_YOUR_APPLE_ID".
3. Nuke the MAS code-signing files. Ctrl+click on XCode > Show Package Contents, Cmd+Del on _MASReceipt.

Comment: I have no clue what "Nuking" means, sorry too new to Mac.

Comment: I mean delete, of course. That's alright Dinesh, for me English is a second language.